# Why does Rails not add indices by default to a join table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, indexing, rails-migrations, join

The Rails Guide on Active Record Migrations section 3.2 [Creating a Join Table](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#creating-a-join-table) says that indices are not added by default to join tables:

> create_join_table also accepts a block, which you can use to add
>   indices (which are not created by default) or additional columns:

When I run the generator, I can indeed see that at least some indices are not added by default:

```
class CreateJoinTableFooBar < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_join_table :foos, :bars do |t|
      # t.index [:foo_id, :bar_id]
      # t.index [:bar_id, :foo_id]
    end
  end
end
```

What is the rationale for Rails not adding these indices by default?

Also, just to clarify, if I don't uncomment these lines, will any indices for :foo_id or :bar_id by itself be generated?

Comment: I am not a huge expert on indices, but my guess is that having both of those indices don't really make much sense. Depending on your data, there might be a big performance difference between those, and it should be up to the developer to decide which one to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> not added by default to **HABTM** join tables

The key is here: `HABTM`

[`has_and_belongs_to_many`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) is meant to be a way to simply connect two or more sets of data together. There is no need for primary indexes - simply two sets of `foreign_keys`

[image]

---

The reason you may wish to add indices etc is because of [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) (which is used standalone predominantly to give you extra attributes in the join).

Although `has_many :through` is meant to give you the ability to use a central model to join two others...

[image]

... it is often used just as a join model (IE in the example above, the join model could be called `physician_patients`).

If you were using `has_many :through` in this capacity, you'd want to have indices in your join table.